# Unity sphere over light flare

Tags: unity-game-engine

in Unity I have a lens flare like this:

[image]

And a sphere mesh (with sphere collider) like this:

[image]

I would like the result to come out like this:

[image]

Adding the layer that the sphere is on to the Lens Flare "Ignore Layers" list makes the lens flare be drawn on top of the sphere, while taking it off the "Ignore Layers" list means the lens flare isn't drawn at all. How can I just draw the lens flare behind the sphere?

Comment: did you alredy try to use a second camera?

Comment: I haven't, but that seems like a clumsy solution.